# Deletion of C# *.resx files for a solution (how many resx files needed per project)

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces, resx

I have a C# project which consists of several solutions (each contained within a separate folder).  Several of the solutions use the same namespace (properties -> Default namespace).  When you build the project, the auto-generated Resources.Designer.cs files which are in solutions having identical namespaces conflict with one another.  You get the following warning message:

The type 'xxx.xxx.xxx.Resources' in 'c:\xxx\solution1\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs' conflics with the imported type 'xxx.xxx.xxx.Resources' in 'c:\xxx\mainProject\bin\somedll.dll'.  Using type defined in 'c:\xxx\solution1\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs'.

The reason for this warning message that I have duplicate method name within files with same name, within the same namespace.

I see two possible solutions.  I could rename the solution namespaces.  I could delete some of the auto-generated Resources.Designer.cs (.resx) files.

The project is referenced by other projects ... so instead of changing the namespace, decided to delete some of the Resources.Designer.cs files.  This did get rid of the warning messages.

QUESTION:
1. Is there a downside or danger in deleting the auto-generated Resources.Designer.cs files in solutions?
2. How many Resources.Designer.cs are needed for one project?
3. Is there a better way to get rid of this warning messages which I did not think of?

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the namespaces? Seems the cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will probably end up doing as you said.  I was just wondering if deleting some of the *.resx files within the same namespace would work as well.